# Laravel Inline Css for mailgun

Tags: php, laravel

im using Mailgun to send mail notifications and i have an issue. My inline css works fine except display:flex and justify-contents, color, padding and etc works good, but i want to use display flex and justify content with align items which not recognized by gmail, why is this like this? :d

Comment: Can you provide an example code of what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML styling in e-mail is notoriously difficult to do. Here's a reference guide to see what is supported:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

And specifically for your flexbox:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/flexbox/

As you can see, all e-mail clients support different things. Why? Either for security reasons, lack of interest, or more nefarious reason.

The best advice I can give is: Keep it simple.